# Какая пунктуация будет правильной?

Tags: прямая-речь, пунктуация

Добрый день.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Какая пунктуация будет правильной?

1. На такой простой вопрос, как: "Как ты думаешь?" мне достаточно жёстко отвечали, какое твоё дело, что и как я думаю, воображая из себя мыслителя.
2. На такой простой вопрос, как: "Как ты думаешь?" мне достаточно жёстко отвечали: "Какое твоё дело, что и как я думаю...", воображая из себя мыслителя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможные варианты:

На   простой вопрос "Как ты думаешь?" мне достаточно жёстко отвечали, какое твоё дело, что и как я думаю, воображая из себя мыслителя.

На  такой простой вопрос: "Как ты думаешь?" - мне достаточно жёстко отвечали, какое твоё дело, что и как я думаю, воображая из себя мыслителя.

Исправляю вторую часть:

На  такой простой вопрос: "Как ты думаешь?" - мне достаточно жёстко отвечали: "Какое твоё дело, что и как я думаю, воображая из себя мыслителя?".

Здесь нельзя использовать косвенную речь, так как в ответе заключен вопрос.

Comment: Verа,не знаю,кто и что изменил в ответе,но сейчас у  Вас явная ошибка-смешение прямой и косвенной речи."...мне достаточно жёстко отвечали, какое ТВОЁ дело "...В косвенной не может быть 1 и 2 лица , там только от 3 лица. Лучше было оставить прямую речь:На такой простой вопрос,как "Как ты думаешь?", мне достаточно жёстко отвечали: "Какое твоё дело, что и как я думаю...",воображая из себя мыслителя.После КАК двоеточия нет,потому что здесь чужая речь используется в сравнительном обороте(такой вопрос, как...- как член предложения).После прямой речи можно тире не ставить, т.к.дальше д.-п. оборот

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд правильнее первый вариант. Во втором можно было бы не оформлять второй ответ как прямую речь, если бы там, скажем, было бы так: "...отвечали, что, мол, какое мое дело, что и как они думают, при этом воображая себя мыслителями".

Comment: Но ведь прямую речь использует как раз 2 вариант, а косвенной здесь не может быть, потому что чужая речь даётся без изменений - с использованием притяжат.местоимения  "твоё дело"(от 2 лица)

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном примере явная прямая речь, поэтому нужно двоеточие.Только не совсем понятно к чему относится последнее предложение "воображая из себя мыслителя": входит ли оно в прямую речь или относится к словам автора?

Вера,скажите,пожалуйста, а на основе какого правила вы поставили тире во втором примере?

Comment: Если на месте разрыва прямой речи не знаков препинания, то ставится универсальное тире: Со словами: «Прощайте и будьте здоровы» – он вышел из комнаты.   На мой вопрос: «Жив ли старый смотритель?» – никто не мог мне дать ответа. Из дрожек выскочил человек и с криком: «Евгений Васильевич!» – бросился к Базарову.

Comment: Это не прямая речь разрывается, а авторская, вернеепрямая речь внутри авторских слов. А тире или запятая и тире здесь ставятся по условиям контекста